# Silly Question on Excluded Middle

Tags: logic

This is perhaps a silly question, but here it is. As I understand, the law of excluded middle is Aristotelian, and is typically written $P \vee \neg P$, or in vernacular that a given statement is true or not true. My confusion is on the word "or." I understand that in math, there is a difference between the exclusive or "Xor" and the "real" or. For example, a rose is "red or thorny," but not "red Xor thorny." My question is, in the statement "P or not P," are we using the "real or," or the "exclusive or"? If the law of excluded middle is of Aristotelian origin, then I have trouble imagining it allowing the statement "P and not P," as I'd think this would run counter to Classical ideas of logic; furthermore, this would leads to problems of explosion, which I was led to believe was not typically appreciated in mathematical settings. But on the other hand, the use of "or" (and more irritatingly, the use of the $\vee$ symbol) suggests otherwise. Could somebody please clear this up?

Thanks.

Comment: See in [Contradiction](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/contradiction/#LEMLNC) : "The twin foundations of Aristotle's logic are the law of non-contradiction (LNC) (also known as the law of contradiction) and the law of excluded middle (LEM)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the inclusive or.  But there is also a separate principle, called the [principle of non-contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction),  $$\lnot(P\land \lnot P)$$ which says that $P$ can't be both true and not true.

The law of the excluded middle says it must be one or the other, or both, and the law of non-contradiction says it can't be both.  So if both laws hold, you can prove that $P\oplus\lnot P$ is true, where $\oplus$ means exclusive or.

In [paraconsistent logics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic), the law of non-contradiction does not hold, and $P$ can indeed be both true and not true; then $P\oplus \lnot P$ does not necessarily hold.

(Your question is not silly.)